# How to override responseInterceptor method in InMemoryBackendService of in-memory web api for Angular2?

Tags: http, angular, httpresponse, in-memory-database, in-memory

I am using POST request to update one property of an object based on passed id as parameter. The default response I am getting is an object consisting only property which I have updated. I want to get the whole updated object in response so that I can show some updated property of this object in front end.

This is the object:

```
{
    id: 1001,
    status: 'EN',
    overall_progress: 78,
    difference: 2
},
```

I am sending following POST request:

```
const url = `${this.progressUrl}/${nodeId}`;
    var json = JSON.stringify({progress_data : { status: resourceStatus }});
    return this.http.post(url, json, { headers: this.headers })
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
```

The response I am getting is

```
{id : 1001, status: "CO"}
```

Can someone help me understand how can I get the whole object in response by overriding "responseInterceptor" method?